# Dynamically refer to cells in Excel Workbook saved on Sharepoint

Tags: function, sharepoint

We have various workbooks with detail calculations saved on SharePoint.
I would like to compile a summary of information residing in these workbooks in a new workbook (also on SharePoint)

I would like the user to specify the workbook name, the sheet name and file path will be constant, and the cell references will be pre-defined.

See high level outline below:

| File Name | B7 | B8 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| File1.xlsx | =GetValue(Path,File1.xlsx,sheet name, B7) | =GetValue(Path,File1.xlsx,Sheet name, B8) |
| File2.xlsx | =GetValue(Path,File2.xlsx,Sheet name, B7) | '=GetValue(Path,File2.xlsx,Sheet name, B8) |

[Workbook set-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVw8t.png)

I tried the following code:

```
Function GetValue(ByVal path As String, ByVal fileName As String, ByVal sheetName As String, ByVal cellReference As String) As Variant
    
    ' Open the external workbook 
    Dim externalWorkbook As Workbook
    Set externalWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=path & fileName, ReadOnly:=True)
    
    ' Reference the cell in the external workbook 
    GetValue = externalWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Range(cellReference).value
    
    ' Close the external workbook without saving changes 
    externalWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
End Function
```

Running it with a test sub and `Debug.Print` function gives the correct answer, but running it as a function in an Excel cell gives a #VALUE Error, any help or alternative suggestion would be appreciated.